# How to change a value of a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a dictionary

```
public static IDictionary<string, IList<string>> checksCollection = 
           new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();
```

I add to the dictionary as follows:

```
public static void addCheck(string checkName, string hostName, 
          string port, string pollInterval, string alertEmail, 
          string alertSMS, string alertURI)
{
    checksCollection.Add(checkName, new[] { checkName, hostName, port, 
               pollInterval, alertEmail, alertSMS, alertURI });
}
```

How would it be possible to change the `alertURI` list value?

Comment: Your example shows how you add code, but it does show where you would modify `alertUri`. Can you code that explains what you are looking to do?

Comment: @HackedByChinese Hi, Upon the record being added to the dictionary I would simply like to update the "alertURI" value within the dictionary

Comment: Rather than repeat checkName as the dictionary key use a keyed collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way, by getting the `IList<string>` from the dictionary and accessing its seventh element:

```
checksCollection[checkName][6] = "new value";
```

But if I were you, I'd make all those values in the string array its own class so you don't have to hardcode the index values, just in case you add or remove additional properties in the future. Create a class definition like so:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string CheckName { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string PollInterval { get; set; }
    public string AlertEmail { get; set; }
    public string AlertSMS { get; set; }
    public string AlertURI { get; set; }
}
```

And change your dictionary definition:

```
public static IDictionary<string, YourClass> checksCollection = 
    new Dictionary<string, YourClass>();
```

And then to add to it (although preferably you would create a constructor on `YourClass` that takes the parameters):

```
public static void addCheck(string checkName, string hostName, string port, string pollInterval, string alertEmail, string alertSMS, string alertURI)
{
    checksCollection.Add(checkName, new YourClass() { 
        CheckName = checkName,
        HostName = hostName,
        Port = port,
        PollInterval = pollInterval,
        AlertEmail = alertEmail,
        AlertSMS = alertSMS,
        AlertURI = alertURI
    });
}
```

And then modifying becomes straightforward with no guesswork of array indices:

```
checksCollection[checkName].AlertURI = "new value";
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to do

```
checksCollection["somekey"][6] = "new value for alertURI"
```

I'd recommend creating a small object that represents those 7 values, something like

```
class Foo {
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string PollInterval { get; set; }
    public string AlertEmail { get; set; }
    public string AlertSMS { get; set; } 
    public string AlertURI { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could change it by

```
checksCollection["key"].AlertURI = "something else";
```